# "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred.." on Production Server Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, deployment

This is probably something simple but i just cannot figure it out so i'm just going to put it out there. In my c# class library i have a connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\As.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

And this works fine in my local development environment. However this class library needs to be consumed by a web component and thus i need to upload it to my ISP. When i try this in my local IIS, i have to put the database files in the App_Data folder of my web service app and it works great. When i upload it the ISP server (and put the database files in the App_Data folder) i get the error
***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.***

What have i got wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is MS SQL Server Express available at the ISP server? Is there an instance running on the server that is named SQLEXPRESS?

I doubt that they are running a SQL Server Express instance on the web server.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance on the server is named SQLEXPRESS? Could you try to remove the "User Instance=True" part?

Comment: No it wasn't. I forgot about that completely. Thanks.